# How to specify the many to one models in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, database, django-models

I'm trying to link two models: `Department` and `User`. They have a many-to-one relation.
A `department` can have only `admin` (User) and a `department` can have many users.
A `User` can only be in one department.

Here is my code

```
class Department(models.Model):
    admin    = models.ForeignKey("applications.User", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class User(AbstractUser, models.Model):
    username      = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    department    = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="members")
```

But I'm having this error:

```
ERRORS:
applications.Department.admin: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Department.admin' clashes with field name 'User.department'.
        HINT: Rename field 'User.department', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Department.admin'.
```

I need to keep attributes naming as is.
How to properly fix and model the relation between the tables?

Is django assuming that Department may have many admins?

Comment: No, Django is not assuming anything. just add `related_name` argument to the Department.admin model with value `department_admin` or whatever you like and it's done. This will change only reverse lookup field name.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `related_name` argument to the `Department.admin`? And **Django** is assuming that an admin might have many departments not the other way around.